# How to align an autoadjust size using database fields in crystalreport?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I have a question I'm using vs2015 and crystalreport CRforVS_13_0_18. I designed my report but when this report has a field longer than the others columns, only this grows, Even I set all the fields to check the option Can Grows. Can you help me?. Thanks in advance. I share a snapshot.[image]

And this is my designer.
[image]

When I put borders, they don't show with the same height. like this:
[image]

I did the extra section but i have problems with left and right lines.
[image]

Finally. i got to do lines untill the end of the section but how can i align in vertical center? please.
[image]

Comment: Try placing the box around them and Tick/check 'Extend to bottom of section when printing' - and give color to box instead of fields...

Comment: Is it possible to create a format formula to calculate for example the high of a database field "NOMBRE" and with this value put in the other fields? Iti Tyagi

Comment: Are you putting separate boxes for each field? or Section box? I am suggesting to put the box in Section 3 (Details). But I think it will expand around the complete table instead of each row when previewed. But can you test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add another section below Section 3. Let's call this Section N.
2. Put a horizontal line (as long as table width in Section 3) in this Section N, and decrease the height of this
       section to as low as possible.
3. Reduces it only leave space for this horizontal like to be visible.

Now when you will be run the report, section N will be printed for every section 3 (row) and can help in drawing a line after each row.

Comment: Tahnks a lot Tyagi It helped me but there is a little problem. I put a new image in the post to show you how the left and rigth lines are smaller than others.

Comment: under Format Line (for vertical), check the "Extend to Bottom of Section", does that help? Means removed datafield borders else they will look like line when expanding and add manual lines to separate fields.

Comment: I appreciate your help, you're ok i did the lines setted in Extend to Button and I got it but the problem is that the content of some cell are not aligned in center vertical. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please show the "Informe principal view" if you can, to get a more clear picture.

So the field in description for item nº2 and 3 should grow ?

Can you try this:

1. Did you check the field in sql ?
2. Are the labels (Nº, Cant, Cod.Barras ...) on different sections than the fields ?
3. Are the fields you wanna grow on Details ?
4. Did you set a printer ?

Comment: Hello, I checked sql they are in, the labels are in section 2 and the fields in section 3, the fields are in Details, An the printer I don't understand how do I do that?