# Dynamic data formatting & table insertion feature in SAP Crystal Report ASP Web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, dataset

I have to generate report on .aspx page through Crystal Report, my report includes different tables. 
I am following below steps to do so:

1. Create Standard Report Wizard in ASP Web Application in Visual Studio
2. Add Dataset with Datatable  with Columns(same name as column name in SQL query)
3. Drag & Drop Col names in 'Details Section' (it will automatically add same as heading in "Page Header" Section.
4. Drag down Section 4 to arrange all data within the Details section
5. For Columns consuming much area increase their height, all formatting including font styles, text cell allignment , col size etc are easily formatible.
6. For different part of data(small tables etc), Sub Reports are used

**testpage.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Back to Input Page" />
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" ToolPanelView="None" />
```

**testpage.aspx.cs**

```
    public partial class testpage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
            string ticketgotsession, query;
            string conString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        ticketgotsession = Session["ticketno"].ToString();
        ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Crystest4.rpt"));

   //All different queries combined in 1 query & stored in Dataset obj t1 
    test1 t1 = GetQ1("select c1,c2,c3.....c30 
          from table1
          inner join  table2 on ___
          inner join table3 on ___
          inner join table4 on ___
         where cr.ref_num='" + ticketgotsession + "'");

         crystalReport.SetDataSource(t1);
         CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
      }

private test1 GetQ1(string query)
{
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.Connection = con;

            sda1.SelectCommand = cmd1;

            using (test1 t1 = new test1())
            {   //DataTable4 was empty table of dataset test1 with Exactly same name as all Col names in the query
                sda1.Fill(t1,"DataTable4");
                return t1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the report designed so far (Encircled: cell borders for cells created using Lines manually, data exceeds out of 1 cell or sometimes it overprints over another content).
[image]

Links have also been referred : [auto-adjust size using datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185665/how-to-align-an-autoadjust-size-using-database-fields-in-crystalreport) and [Using Tight Horizontal](https://answers.sap.com/questions/8832761/field-formatting---expand-to-fit-horizontally.html)

However, after many experiments, below was observed with ***Can Grow* & *Tight Horizontal*** feature:

> "When Can Grow & Tight Horizontal both are Enabled
>   then
>   Columns are Vertically Expanded But not Horizontally, 
>   no text truncated"
>
> "When Tight Horizontal is Enabled, Border will be trimmed to match the size of each individual record."

But nothing worked.

As there is **Grid View in asp.net**, which aligns data dynamically in  tabular layout, I am **looking for similar feature in Crystal Report**, so that I don't have to drag and drop each data field then resize, set boundaries  each of them manually.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Does the user see the report preview? 
Or do you need to deliver the end result as print/export format? If so, which format?

Comment: Yes, firstly the report is displayed (code in testpage.aspx above) to the user, and based on their requirement, report can be printed/exported through the Print/Export options resp. provided by SAP Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you have 2 main options:

1. Improve the layout design, possibly using dynamic size/position expressions. If font is proportional you can create or use a 3rd-party Crystal UFL (User Function Library) to compute size for a given content and font.
2. In code, use a grid control or HTML table, convert result to image, and display the image in the report. Again, you can create or use a 3rd-party Crystal UFL to do that. Here is an example of output from a Crystal formula using a 3rd-party UFL that converts HTML text to an image for embedding in the report:[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response! Well, I will first search about 3rd-party Crystal UFL (User Function Library) what it actually is and will try to implement in my project, I hope it will work with lenthy tables with variable length data.